# Link error: QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, qt, linker

While compiling a QT project on a Mac, I encounter the following error

```
ld: file not found: QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore for architecture x86_64
```

which is not true because I have a 64bit architecture available, as shown below

```
$ cd
/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4
$ file QtCore
QtCore: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
QtCore (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
QtCore (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

What seems to be the problem?

Update:
The ld command line is

```
/usr/bin/c++   -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   -compatibility_version 1.0.0 -current_version 1.0.5 -o libjreen.1.0.5.dylib -install_name /Users/sb/Work/QuiKast/jabber/libjreen-1.0.5/build/libjreen.1.dylib ./src/abstractroster.cpp.o ./src/action.cpp.o ./3rdparty/jdns/moc_qjdns.cpp.o ./3rdparty/jdns/moc_qjdns_p.cpp.o -F/usr/local/lib /opt/local/lib/libQtNetwork.dylib /opt/local/lib/libQtCore.dylib -framework qca /usr/lib/libz.dylib
```

and

```
$ file /opt/local/lib/libQtCore.dylib 
/opt/local/lib/libQtCore.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Comment: Likely you are linking against another library. Do you have multiple Qt installations? Check your PATH. Anyway, to help you it would be useful to known OSX and Qt versions.

Comment: The OSX version is 10.6.8 and the Qt version 4.7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
-framework QtCore
```

solved this issue